# Regex to remove url parameter

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having trouble writing a regex that removes any of these parameters from a url using javascript:

> pricerange=-#
>
> pricerange=#-#
>
> pricerange=#-

This works ok for all except the last one. It doesn't remove pricerange=40-

```
var postUrl = "http://www.test.com/directory/?cat=203604&pricerange=-10&pricerange=10-20&pricerange=20-30&pricerange=30-40&pricerange=40-" 

postUrl = postUrl.replace(/[&\?]\bpricerange\=[0-9]*-[0-9]*\b/g, "");
```

Result:

```
http://www.test.com/directory/?cat=203604&pricerange=40-
```

Expected result:

```
http://www.test.com/directory/?cat=203604
```

Here is the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fonaqibinaqu/2/edit).

There could be other parameters in the url that I wouldn't want to remove.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it again after removing ending `\b`

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pT6dN2/1)

OR use `(\b|$)` to match either word boundary or end of the line

Corrected [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pT6dN2/2)

---

Your regex will not work correctly if `cat=203604` is some where in between `pricerange` query parameters.

for example:

```
http://www.test.com/directory/?pricerange=-10&cat=203604&pricerange=10-20&pricerange=20-30&pricerange=30-40&pricerange=40-
```

Output: (Query parameter should be started by ?)

```
http://www.test.com/directory/&cat=203604
```

You can correct it, using `&*\bpricerange\=[0-9]*-[0-9]*&*`

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pT6dN2/12)

Comment: Specifically voting up the second version. Also, no need for the `\b` after the `[&\?]`, so: `/[&\?]pricerange\=[0-9]*-[0-9]*(\b|$)/g`

Comment: Yes you are right. No need to use `\b` because `[&\?]` is already defined as prefix

Comment: @PaulRoub `\b` is needed. Look at the updated post. There is one more fault in OP regex patern.

Comment: It's just in Demo, I have test it programmatic with `str.replace` function and it works perfectly.

Comment: I guess the only issue is if the url is this "http://www.test.com/directory/?pricerange=10-20" then the '?' stays there.

Comment: Sorry, still not there. This one doesn't work: http://www.test.com/directory/?pricerange=-10&pricerange=10-20

Comment: Simply try `&*\bpricerange\=[0-9]*-[0-9]*&*` and remove the `?` if left in the end.

Comment: The regex doesn't work for this sample: http://www.test.com/directory/?param1=1&pricerange=-10&param2=3&pricerange=10-20

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/pT6dN2/13

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a regular expression? We're going through a lot of gymnastics to make that happen. A function would do the job:

```
function cleaner(url)
{
  var parts = url.split("?");

  if (parts.length == 2)
    {
      var comps = parts[1].split('&');

      for ( var i = comps.length - 1; i >= 0; --i )
        {
          if (comps[i].match(/^pricerange=\d*\-\d*$/))
            comps.splice(i, 1);
        }

      if (comps.length > 0)
        parts[1] = comps.join('&');
      else
        parts.splice(1, 1);
    }

  return parts.join("?");
}

var postUrl = "http://www.test.com/directory/?cat=203604&pricerange=-10&pricerange=10-20&pricerange=20-30&pricerange=30-40&pricerange=40-" 

postUrl = cleaner(postUrl);
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/srfCj

Comment: Thank you. Also a good suggestion. Probably easier to maintain.